# TVDB api GET Ajax not working jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, jwt

I can't figure out what the hell im doing wrong here, feeling pretty dumb.

Essentially, I am trying to access the tvdb api but it will not work from my app using ajax. However I can get it to work just fine using a curl or using https://www.hurl.it/ to make the request.

The following curl is successful and has no problem accessing the api:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer {my jwt token here}' 'https://api.thetvdb.com/search/series?name=simpsons'
```

As you can see its just a get request with an authorization header which should be 'Bearer {token}'

However, I cannot figure out why my ajax request is not working:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.thetvdb.com/search/series?name=simpsons",
    type:'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'
    },
    success:function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

The response I get says not authorized even though I am sending the token exactly as it is in my successful curl. I am at a loss, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Try this:

```
var access_token = 'pwwbkvv7abqzonnvztpea91ich7vprwdorbt4w4m';
$.ajax({
  url: "https://api.thetvdb.com/search/series?name=simpsons",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error:function(err) {
        console.log(err);
  },
  beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) { xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + access_token); } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, doesn't seem to work for me though. As far as that token goes, mine is like 5x longer though. I suspect there is something else im missing or something with the way the app is set up...